# The method search() in the type "x" is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jsp

Setup Mac OSX 10.6.7, Eclipse, Tomcat 1.6

I am trying to call a string from a Java file to my JSP to display it to the user but I keep getting the below error. Any help is as always much appreciated,

The JSP

```
<%
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceInjector());
SliceConnector r = injector.getInstance(SliceConnector.class);  
out.println(r.search());    

String dbConcept = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/human_rights";
System.out.println(r.search(dbConcept));
%>
```

The Java

```
public String search(String dbConcept)
{
    setSlicepediaProductionMode(true);

    List<SliceHit> sliceHits = searchForSlices();
    if (sliceHits == null) {
        System.err.println("Timeout occurred while fetching slices");
        return "error";
    }
    if (!sliceHits.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Found some slices Yuhuuuu ! :-) ");
        String sliceContent = createSlices(sliceHits);
        System.out.println("Slice content:");
        System.out.println(sliceContent);
        return sliceContent;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Slices were found for this query");
    }
    System.out.println("Slice Consumer stopped activity");      
    return "SliceConnector";
}

private void setSlicepediaProductionMode(boolean productionMode)
{
    sliceSearcher.setProductionMode(productionMode);
    sliceCreator.setProductionMode(productionMode);
}
private List<SliceHit> searchForSlices() {
    SlicepediaQuery sliceQuery = new SlicepediaQuery();

    String dbConcept = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/human_rights";

    sliceSearcher.setSliceQuery(sliceQuery);
    if (sliceSearcher.run()) 
    {
        return sliceSearcher.getSliceHits();
    } else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Error

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 141 in the jsp file: /SimpleResponse2.jsp
The method search() in the type SliceConnector is not applicable for the arguments (String)
138:            
139:            
140:        String dbConcept = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/human_rights";
141:        System.out.println(r.search(dbConcept));
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: @GriffeyDog This is a project I inherited from another developer. Its an absolute behemoth of a project and is missing files all over the place. Unfortunately I can’t rebuild or even debug it in Eclipse. Not a good way to start learning Java or JSP

Comment: It would appear that the code you posted for SliceConnector is not the version that is compiled and on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are calling search() twice, first without argument, the second time with a string. In the code posted you only provide for the latter case, so you should already get an error at the first call.

Correct the first call and make sure you are referencing to the right file(s).

Comment: The error he's getting would indicate the problem is indeed with the second call, and that the method `search()` is defined without any parameters. That's why I suggested cleaning and rebuilding the project.